# Can't get data from the database using map(res => res["data"]) Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using Angular 12 with xampp to access my phpmyadmin database.
I can connect to the database and insert to it, but I can't bring the data from it and show it on my page.

This is my Employee-list.component.ts:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { EmployeeService } from './../employee.service'
import { Employee } from './../employee'
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-list',
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css'],
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  employees!: Observable<Employee[]>
  employee: Employee = new Employee()
  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService, private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData()
  }
  reloadData() {
    console.log(this.employeeService.getEmployeesList(this.employee))
    this.employee.setOperation('listePersonne')
    this.employees = this.employeeService.getEmployeesList(this.employee)
  }
  deleteEmployee(id: number) {
    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.reloadData()
      },
      (error) => console.log(error)
    )
  }
  employeeDetails(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['details', id])
  }
  updateEmployee(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['update', id])
  }
}
```

And this is my employee.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { Employee } from './employee'
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EmployeeService {
  // private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/employees';
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost/tpangularmysql/gestiPersonne.php'
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getEmployee(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}?operation=getInfoPersonne&personne_id=${id}`)
  }
  createEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<Object> {
    console.log(employee)
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, employee)
  }
  updateEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}?operation=modifierPersonne`, employee)
  }
  deleteEmployee(id: number): Observable<any> {
    console.log(`${this.baseUrl}?operation=supprimerPersonne/${id}`)
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}?operation=supprimerPersonne&personne_id=${id}`, {
      responseType: 'text',
    })
  }
  getEmployeesList(employee: Employee): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}?operation=` + employee.operation).pipe(map((res) => res['data']))
  }
}
```

Now my problem comes in the line of `map(res => res["data"])` in employee.service.ts.
I get these errors :

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"data"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
> Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Whats `console.log({res})`?

Comment: Methods in `EmployeeService` are of type `Observable<any>` but you shold avoid using `any`. Can you share response code examples to create interfaces and improve typing?

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix is change this:

```
getEmployeesList(employee: Employee): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}?operation=` + employee.operation).pipe(map((res) => res['data']))
}
```

to this:

```
getEmployeesList(employee: Employee): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}?operation=` + employee.operation).pipe(map((res: any) => res['data']))
}
```

Another alternative is to turn off `NoImplicitAny` in tsconfig.

Although, both the above solutions are essentially just bypassing typing, which is not good.

It is better to use interfaces to type your HTTP response.